# Boto hangs on s3 key read

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto

Having an issue reading some large keys using `boto`, and I'm not really finding any documentation that points to the issue that I'm having. I've got a key in `s3` that's ~3gb of bson, but I have it being read from a co-located ec2 instance that supposedly has a 10 gigabit connection and 244 gb of ram (an r3.8xlarge), so that really shouldn't be the problem.

Code is reproduced below, but just generally wondering if there are tips for either getting an indication that either a read is actually progressing, or if there's something fundamentally wrong with our connection.

```
def redistribute(self):
    w_queue = mp.Queue()
    for bucket in self.buckets:
        for key in self.conn.get_bucket(bucket).list():
            documents = key.read().split('~#^#~')[:-1]  # Hangs on this line
            total = len(documents)
            i = 0.0
            documents = chunk(documents, 100)
            for chunk in documents:
                for line in chunk:
                    w_queue.put(line)
                pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
                pool.apply_asynch(self.write, w_queue)
                w_queue.join()
```

Boto Function:

```
def read(self, size=0):
    self.open_read()
    if size == 0:
        data = self.resp.read()  # Specifically hangs on this line
    else:
        data = self.resp.read(size)
    if not data:
        self.close()
    return data
```

Comment: I've found that boto is less great with big files. In my case, we use c++ too so we let it handle those.

Comment: @Finch_Powers How does using c++ solve this problem? This is just an http request.

Comment: What region is the bucket and instance in?

Comment: @garnaat co-located in us-west-2.

Comment: And are you connecting to the us-west-2 S3 endpoint explicitly?  Or are you connecting to the generic S3 endpoint?  I'm not sure if this would make a difference or not but I have seen situations in the past where people connect to the generic endpoint and the subsequent redirect can cause a problem.

Comment: One other question, when it hangs have you been able to look at the process size?  Is it increasing?  The read() call will read the entire thing into memory so you should see the process size increase if anything is happening.

Comment: @garnaat that's a great idea! I actually hadn't looked at the process size, will report back with results.